# How to set the Returning Property in KISSMetrics?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, kissmetrics

I am integrating KISSMetrics into my rails app via Javascript and Rails itself (depending on the event type).

How do I set the Returning Property for visitors in KISSMetrics?

The documentation implies that it's automatically set by KISS, as long as my app identifies the user consistently.  I've confirmed that KISS is able to identify the user consistently via the Live dashboard, which shows that KISS has logged the anonymized user ID number, URL and referrer property for the visit.

However, despite repeat visits to my test site with the same user, I do not see any Returning property being set.  It's not shown in the Live dashboard.  Nor is it available as a property in reports or metrics.

Am I missing a step here?  Or do I need to wait a day for?  I've already given it about 8 hours, whereas the guidance on delays in KISS seems to be anywhere from a few minutes to 6 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning parameter is set automatically by the system - nothing needs to be configured. The confusion is that there is a significant delay between when the event first happens (a returning visitor) and when it is reported by their system.  This is in contrast to Rails-fired events (seen almost immediately).